# Get the Description of Product Variations Attributes terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

In Woocommerce I have these attributes and the terms for them:

```
color: blue(description=1), red(description=2)
size:  xl(description=10),  m(description=20)
```

All terms have description fields mentioned above.

For a variable product, I have these variations:

```
blue-m 
red-xl
```

For the purpose of auto-generating the variations SKU (based on those descriptions) I need to get the description for the attribute term used in each variant (we use different attributes for each variable product).

For example for the variation with `red` color and `xl` size, I want to get something like `210` (from descriptions of `red` and `xl`)

I tried using `$variation['attributes']` and removing extra characters from it to use with `get_terms` to get the descriptions of the attributes used in a variant, but I couldn't succeed.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in an easily once you get the Product variation ID `$variation_id` this way:

```
// Initializing
$variation_sku = '';

// Get the product variation object (instance)
$variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

// Loop through variation attributes "taxonomy" / "terms" pairs
foreach( $variation->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute => $value ){
    $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $attribute );
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
    // $term_name = $term->name;
    $variation_sku .= $term->description; // <= HERE the Description
}
// Displaying the sku
echo '<p>'.__("SKU: ").$variation_sku.'</p>';
```

Comment: Awesome! just for reference: `$term_description` gives the description of the last attribute in the variation, to get the description of all attributes used in the variation (as I mentioned in the example with `210` ) I just used `$term_description[]` and `$variation_sku = implode( $term_description )`